# Typescript reports unused-var in enums

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In my React project I've got this code:
`export enum Tab {BASIC = 'BASIC', ADVANCED = 'ADVANCED', SETTINGS = 'SETTINGS'}`

Each of the enum cases are giving me a warning that they are assigned but never used.

I've seen a few solutions and they don't seem to work. First off here is my tsconfig and eslintrc. You can see that I have `parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser'`. Also in my package.json: `"eslint-plugin-typescript": "^1.0.0-rc.3"` and in devDependencies: `"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.7.0", "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.7.0",`

#### tsconfig

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

#### eslintrc.js

```js
module.exports = {
    env: {
        browser: true,
        es6: true,
    },
    extends: [
        'react-app',
    ],
    globals: {
        Atomics: 'readonly',
        SharedArrayBuffer: 'readonly',
    },
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaFeatures: {
            jsx: true,
        },
        ecmaVersion: 2018,
        sourceType: 'module',
    },
    plugins: [
        'react',
        '@typescript-eslint',
    ],
    rules: {},
};
```

I've also tried adding `'@typescript-eslint'` to `extends` in eslintrc but then it says `failed to load @typescript-eslint to extend from`

How can I fix this?

Comment: do you have tslint.json file?

Comment: No I'm using eslint not tslint